# nan in gradients when nan in inputs even if loss computation is correct

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some inputs with NaNs that I can't replace as a preprocessing. I nevertheless would like to  use the autodifferenciation of tensorflow 2.0 to compute the gradients of my operations. 
I built a simple regression case that returns NaN gradients when a NaN is in the inputs. 
Is there a way to have gradients for those operations ?

Best regards

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.float32(np.arange(100))
y = 2*x 
x[0] = np.nan
a = tf.Variable([1e-6])
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    t.watch(a)
    y_pred = a*x
    tensor = tf.reshape((y_pred - y), [-1])**2
    tensor_mask = tf.math.is_nan(tensor)
    tensor_without_nans = tf.where(tensor_mask, tf.zeros_like(tensor), tensor)
    RMSE = tf.reduce_sum(tensor_without_nans, axis=-1)

grads = t.gradient(RMSE,a)
print(grads)
```

Comment: That is interesting, as you say the gradient should be fine, but the problem is that in the end the masking of NaN translates to multiplying NaN times zero in the gradient computation, which is NaN, not zero, so everything turns into NaN later. I'm not sure if there is a way to properly avoid the problem. It works if you mask `x` at the beginning (replace `y_pred = a*x` with `x2 = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(x), tf.zeros_like(x), x); y_pred = a*x2`, then you can skip the masking after), but that may not suit your needs.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer! Indeed that won't work as I m trying to find an optimal affine transformation between two volumes and NaN are added "voluntary" to track the affine transform (I used at first aberrant values) but because of interpolations it resulted in some bias. Best